# exclude weekends to be clickable on jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to prevent the user from clicking on saturdays/sundays (week-ends) when he selects a date using the jQuery UI datepicker widget.

Is there a way to accomplish this? If not, which are the alternatives ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$("#datepicker").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });`